# In Python, how do I take a list and reduce it to a list of duplicates?

Tags: python

I have a list of strings that should be unique. I want to be able to check for duplicates quickly. Specifically, I'd like to be able to take the original list and produce a new list containing any repeated items. I don't care how many times the items are repeated so it doesn't have to have a word twice if there are two duplicates.

Unfortunately, I can't think of a way to do this that wouldn't be clunky. Any suggestions?

EDIT:
Thanks for the answers and I thought I'd make a clarification. I'm not concerned with having a list of uniques for it's own sake. I'm generating the list based off of text files and I want to know what the duplicates are so I can go in the text files and remove them if any show up.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This code should work:

```
duplicates = set()
found = set()
for item in source:
    if item in found:
        duplicates.add(item)
    else:
        found.add(item)
```

Comment: I'll have to make sure this works later but this fits what I was thinking and looks clean.

Comment: Any specific advantage by using set() than lists? 'in' works for lists also?

Comment: @becomingGuru, set() will prevent duplicate additions but is not ordered. Advantages/disadvantages depend on your application

Comment: @coonj: i think he meant set for found, it really is not necessary.

Comment: @becomingGuru: I think 'in' performs better with sets than with lists.  I haven't looked too much into the implementation of this, but my own benchmarks verify it.

Comment: You will then have duplicates in the duplicates list if you don't use a set.

Comment: Sets are hash tables I believe, which means inclusion testing is O(1) on average, whereas inclusion with lists is O(n).

Answer (score 6):

`groupby` from [itertools](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html) will probably be useful here:

```
from itertools import groupby
duplicated=[k for (k,g) in groupby(sorted(l)) if len(list(g)) > 1]
```

Basically you use it to find elements that appear more than once...

NB. the call to `sorted` is needed, as `groupby` only works properly if the input is sorted.

Answer (score 4):

This will create the list in one line:

```
L = [1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4]
L_dup = set([i for i in L if L.count(i) > 1])
```

Comment: Although short, this code has O(N²) performance. For each item in L, a full count of that item in L will be needed. Also only in 2.6

Comment: @Staale, Brian: do you know the typical size of a input Eugene M is working with so that he needs to care about performance?

Comment: Actually N is around 20-50 short strings if that information helps.

Comment: another superfluous use of a list comprehension when a generator expression would do the job.

Answer (score 3):

Definitely not the fastest way to do that, but it seem to work solve the problem:

```
>>> lst = [23, 32, 23, None]
>>> set(i for i in lst if lst.count(i) > 1)
{23}
```

Comment: I like this approach! O(n) and O(n*n) for small lists should be alright.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a simple 1-liner:

```
>>> l = ['a', 'a', 3, 'r', 'r', 's', 's', 2, 3, 't', 'y', 'a', 'w', 'r']
>>> [v for i, v in enumerate(l) if l[i:].count(v) > 1 and l[:i].count(v) == 0]
['a', 3, 'r', 's']
```

`enumerate` returns an indexed list which we use to splice our input list determining whether there are any duplicates ahead of our current index in the loop and whether we have already found a duplicate behind.

Comment: That is horrid code and horrid style (if you must use one-letter names, reserve `j` for an index; use `v` for a value). Slightly less horrid: `[v for i, v in enumerate(L) if v not in L[i+1:] and v not in L[:i]]`

Comment: This is a slow O(n^2) complexity class.

Comment: Acceptable for very small number of unhashable items of mixed types where other solutions are not possible. (mixed tuples, strings, unicode and some unhashable)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't care about the order of the duplicates:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 4, 6, 4, 7, 8, 8]
b = sorted(a)
duplicates = set([x for x, y in zip(b[:-1], b[1:]) if x == y])
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I think this is the simplest way to do it with performance O(n). Similar to vartec's solution but no `import` required and no Python version dependencies to worry about:

```
def getDuplicates(iterable):
    d = {}
    for i in iterable:
        d[i] = d.get(i, 0) + 1
    return [i for i in d if d[i] > 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

the solutions based on 'set' have a small drawback, namely they only work for hashable objects.

the solution based on itertools.groupby on the other hand works for all comparable objects (e.g.: dictionaries and lists).

Answer (score -1):

EDIT : Ok, doesn't work since you want duplicates only.

### Whith python > 2.4 :

You have set, just do :

```
my_filtered_list = list(set(mylist))
```

Set is a data structure that doesn't have duplicate by nature.

### With older Python versions :

```
my_filtered_list = list(dict.fromkeys(mylist).keys())
```

Dictionary map a unique key to a value. We use the "unique" caracteristc to get rid of the duplicate.